# How can I reduce stack and heap size of my application?

Tags: c++, memory, stack, heap-memory

I'm making a simple application to learn more about OpenGL. My application currently generates a small Minecraft-like voxel world divided into chunks and renders it fairly effectively. When troubleshooting my worldgeneration time I found that the application uses quite a bit of memory.

The fully generated world including all pointers to and data for chunks and blocks uses 13,8MB of heap memory measured using sizeof(), however the total size of heap is 62,9MB. Visual Studios heap profiling confirms the size of the generated world to 13,8MB, but doesn't tell me where the remaining 49,1MB of heap size is coming from. How do I find out what causes the large heap size and how do I reduce it?

The total memory used by the process is about 172MB. The 109,1MB not used by heap I assume are allocated in stack, but how can I find out exactly what is stored and start reducing it?

Following here is a few of the functions used in the application to give some context, if more is needed to give a proper answer, please ask me for it! I obviously don't want to paste the entire applications code here since that would be way too much.

This is the function that generates the chunks, each chunk is generated when created.

```
void World::generatechunk(glm::vec2 worldposition)
{
    for (auto c : m_generatedchunks)
    {
        if (c.x == worldposition.x && c.y == worldposition.y)
            return;
    }

    GLfloat** heightmap = new GLfloat* [CHUNK_COLUMNS];
    for (int i = 0; i < CHUNK_COLUMNS; ++i)
        heightmap[i] = new GLfloat[CHUNK_ROWS];

    for (int x = 0; x < CHUNK_COLUMNS; x++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < CHUNK_ROWS; z++)
        {
            heightmap[x][z] = m_simplexfractalnoise.GetNoise(worldposition.x * CHUNK_COLUMNS + x, worldposition.y * CHUNK_ROWS + z);
        }
    }

    m_chunks.push_back(new Chunk(worldposition, m_shader, &heightmap));

    m_generatedchunks.push_back(worldposition);

    for (int i = CHUNK_COLUMNS - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        delete[] heightmap[i];
    delete[] heightmap;
}
```

When created this function is called:

```
void Chunk::generate(GLfloat*** heightmap)
{
    Texture stonetexture("stone.jpg");

    GLuint groundlayer = CHUNK_LAYERS * 0.75f;

    for (GLuint column = 0; column < CHUNK_COLUMNS; ++column)
    {
        for (GLuint layer = 0; layer < CHUNK_LAYERS; ++layer)
        {
            for (GLuint row = 0; row < CHUNK_ROWS; ++row)
            {
                if (layer < groundlayer + CHUNK_LAYERS * 0.5f * (*heightmap)[column][row])
                {
                    m_blocks[column][layer][row] = new Block(column, layer, row, &stonetexture);
                    m_blockssize += sizeof(Block);
                }
                else
                    m_blocks[column][layer][row] = nullptr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything created by these two functions amount to the 13,8MB of heap I mentioned. When a chunk is generated its mesh is also this function:

```
void Chunk::generatemesh()
{
    std::vector<GLfloat> positions;
    std::vector<GLfloat> normals;
    std::vector<GLfloat> texturecoords;
    std::vector<GLuint> indices;

    GLuint currentindex = 0;

    //
    // ...
    // Here is a long block of code that calculated and adds the vertex 
    // and index data to the vectors declared at the start of the function.
    // I don't want to include it all here since this code block would 
    // become too long.
    // The summary of that code is: A lot of floats are added to the 
    // first three vectors, then matching indices to the last vector.
    // ...
    //

    m_elements = static_cast<GLuint>(indices.size());

    for (GLsizei i = 0; i < positions.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0)
            positions[i] += m_worldposition.x * CHUNK_COLUMNS;
        if (i % 3 == 2)
            positions[i] += m_worldposition.y * CHUNK_ROWS;
    }

    GLuint VBOs[3];
    GLuint EBO;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_VAO);
    glGenBuffers(3, VBOs);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(m_VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOs[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positions.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), positions.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, static_cast<GLvoid*>(0));

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOs[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normals.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), normals.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, static_cast<GLvoid*>(0));

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOs[2]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texturecoords.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), texturecoords.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, static_cast<GLvoid*>(0));

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(GLuint), indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLsizei positionssize = sizeof(positions.data());

    std::vector<GLfloat>().swap(positions);
    std::vector<GLfloat>().swap(normals);
    std::vector<GLfloat>().swap(texturecoords);
    std::vector<GLuint>().swap(indices);
}
```

Other than this only class members are the memory I don't delete until the applications termination, but they shouldn't amount to more than a few MBs at most.

The size of the generated world is calculated using these functions:

```
GLsizei World::getsize()
{
    GLsizei size = 0;
    for (auto c : m_chunks)
        size += c->getsize();
    size += sizeof(World);
    return size;
}
```

And:

```
GLsizei Chunk::getsize()
{
    return m_blockssize + sizeof(Chunk);
}
```

The class member `m_blockssize` is incremented by `sizeof(Block)` everytime a block is created and its pointer added to the chunk.

I created a [github repository](https://github.com/lyktstolpe/OpenGL-Application) if its interesting for anyone reading this.

Comment: Can you explain how you calculate memory size using `sizeof`? `sizeof` a vector is not the amount of allocated memory for that vector, just the size of the actual vector object. Your stack by default in Visual Studio is generally about 1MB.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, I added the code that uses sizeof. I avoided using sizeof on the pointers and instead attempted to keep track of the total size of every created object that isn't deleted before termination.

Comment: One thing to think about: in modern programming styles, it's easy to lose track of memory used for pointers and malloc headers. Suppose you need 64k or fewer of a certain kind of binary tree node.  If you allocate each with a malloc having an 8-byte overhead, and the child pointers are both 8 bytes, then 64k nodes require 64k * 3 * 8 even before accounting for data in the nodes. That's 1.4MB of "overhead". The alternative is allocate an array of 64k _contiguous_ nodes and use `unsigned short` indices into the array for pointers. Now we have 64k*2*2 = 256k.